# Ошибка при выполнении процедуры "Not a valid month", но если выполнить в БД, то работает

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

Имеется хранимая процедура, обновляющая значения объектов после выполненных действий.

Проблема в том, что она не выполняется при вызове через WCF сервис, при этом если выполнить ее через СУБД, то все ок.

```
public void SetValues()
{
    var oracleConnection = OraHelper.GetOracleConnection();
    try
    {
        var oracleCommand = OraHelper.CreateStoreProcedureCommand(
            oracleConnection, "PKG_CONN.SetValues");
        oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        oracleConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Процедура:

```
procedure SETMES is
begin   
      --действия процедуры
    COMMIT;
    SETVALUES();
end SETMES;
```

Также, эта процедура вызывается в конце всех процедур, выполняющих некоторые действия, и также она срабатывает, только если вызвать их через СУБД. Действия через вызов из приложения выполняются, но данные не обновляются.

Не могу разобраться, из-за чего такая чудная вещь.

---

PS Вывод в блоке `cath` дал сообщение: "Not a valid month".
В процедуре испoльзую `to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY')`. `to_date` не подходит, пишет - год 0017.

Comment: Как поняли что она не выполняется? Если данные не закомитились, то нужно уточнить где и как данные были изменены.

Comment: У меня результат выполнения одной процедуры изменяет данные в таблице, а эта процедура обновляет значения в другой. После выполнения процедуры из СУБД данные считаются и обновляются, из приложения только изменяют значения в первой таблице без обновления во второй

Comment: Добавьте код метода `OraHelper.GetOracleConnection()`

Comment: public static OracleConnection GetOracleConnection()
        {
            return new OracleConnection
            { ConnectionString = "user id=user1;password=www123;data source=BASE1;" };
        }  

Ошибок в соединении не может быть, т.к. действия других процедур выполняются.

Comment: Так, а соединение Вы где открываете?

Comment: Судя по работающим другим процедурам, соединение устанавливается при создании команды процедуры и ее выполнении, без Open. В других процедурах проблем нет, но из них эта процедура тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: В блок catch что-нибудь добавляли? Если нет, то попробуйте, может вам exception сыпется, а вы и не видите.

Comment: Что-то с форматированием даты, например, месяц с числом местами перепутаны..

Answer (score 2):

Очень каверзная ошибка. В процедуре происходит неявное преобразование символьного значения в дату. Это преобразование зависит от национальных настройк сессии, поэтому одна и таже процедура в одном приложении будет работать, а в другом нет.

Например, в одном приложении:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/rr hh:mi:ss am';

declare 
    d date := to_char (date'2020-07-17','DD.MM.YYYY');
begin dbms_output.put_line (to_char (d, 'dd.mm.yyyy')); end;
/
Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Тот же самый блок, но со следующими настройками сессии:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

Выполнится без ошибки, но потом можно долго искать, откуда взялась такая дата:

> 20.07.0017